# Removing Abs from Abs[a + Exp[I*c]b]^2

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Title says it all. Mathematica produces sometimes expressions of the form

```
Abs[a + Exp[I*c]b]^2
```

where all three quantities a, b and c are positive real numbers. That expression of course reduces simply to the law of cosines

```
a^2 + b^2 + 2a b Cos[c]
```

however, I cannot get Mathematica to display it in this form. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Update

Not sure why all responses here are not simple and direct, maybe in older versions this did not work, but now it does:

```
Abs[a+Exp[I*c] b]^2//ComplexExpand//FullSimplify
```

> a^2+b^2+2 a b Cos[c]

```
(Abs[a+Exp[I*c] b]^2+Abs[a-Exp[I*c] b]^2)/(2 Abs[a+I b]^2)//ComplexExpand//FullSimplify
```

> 1

```
$Version
```

> 14.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 1, 2023)

### Original answer

Until someone figures out how to do it in a better way, here is a work around. Define a function (which is true only for your specific case of parameters):

```
RemoveAbs[x_] := FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Sqrt[x Conjugate[x]]]]
```

Then

```
Abs[a + Exp[I*c] b]^2 /. Abs -> RemoveAbs
```

> a^2 + b^2 + 2 a b Cos[c]

There is a simpler version inspired by @Nasser answer. Define a function

```
RemoveAbs[x_] := ComplexExpand[Abs[x]]
```

and now, for the sake of variety, apply simplification at the end:

```
Abs[a + Exp[I*c] b]^2 /. Abs -> RemoveAbs // FullSimplify
```

> a^2 + b^2 + 2 a b Cos[c]

Point is, all the above will work for more complicated cases because `/.` is a `ReplaceAll`. Even for cases that are convoluted via things like, for example, `TraditionalForm` - the only thing you need is that `InputForm` still has Abs in it. For instance, imagine a beast of expression, here rather a simpler one but in reality they could go for pages:

```
(Abs[a + Exp[I*c] b]^2 + Abs[a - Exp[I*c] b]^2)/(2 Abs[a + I b]^2) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

and now, voila, you get your simplification:

```
% /. Abs -> RemoveAbs // FullSimplify
```

> 1

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[a, c, b];
expr = a + Exp[I*c] b;
Simplify@Expand@(ComplexExpand[Abs@expr]^2)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or in non `@` friendly way

```
Simplify [ Expand [ ComplexExpand[Abs[expr]]^2 ] ]
```

Comment: you are placing ^2 outside of ComplexExpand, he may want to deal with the expression as whole starting from `Abs[a + Exp[I*c]b]^2` . Just noting the difference, but this may work for him too.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I do not see why these are not the same. The above applies `ComplexExpand` on something before squaring, vs. squaring then applying `ComplexExpand` (which will not have simplified). Mathematically these seem to be the same to me since `ComplexExpand` does not add or take anything, but modifies the shape of the expression. But may be I am missing something.

Comment: You are right, mathematically they are the same. But there could be a rather technical issue of order of operations. Imagine you have more complicated expression as I added in my answer below. It is given as whole. Now you need to apply some functions to it to simplify it. Though your assumption is absolutely correct, one still would need to add a few tricks to get this working. I was talking about "tricks", not about the math of it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I like very much the solution of Nasser, especially since it is direct, i.e. it does not use any workaround, but just the Mathematica technique. Not to leave such a basic exercise with only one solution I would like to offer a very simple one:

```
    Clear[exprA, exprB];
exprA = a + Exp[I*c] b
exprB = exprA /. c -> -c (* This produces the conjugated expression *)
   (* a + b E^(I c)    *)
   (*  a + b E^(-I c)  *)
```

Now let us recall that Abs[z]^2=z z* and just multiply

```
    ComplexExpand[exprA*exprB] // Simplify

     (*   a^2 + b^2 + 2 a b Cos[c]  *)
```

It should be noted that I used the replacement c->-c to obtain the conjugated value  using that it is known all parameters to be positive, including c. It can be done in a more general way using Conjugate[]. In this case the final result is the same, but the intermediate results (if one chooses to look at them) are more cumbersome. Anyway,

```
    ComplexExpand[exprA*Conjugate[exprA]] // Simplify
    (* a^2 + b^2 + 2 a b Cos[c]  *)
```