# Simplify with Assumptions Sqrt[(expr)^2]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

While trying to simplify expressions in the form `Sqrt[(expr)^2]` when `expr>0` I noticed a peculiar behavior that was not resolved with code from [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31486/7966).

```
Simplify[Sqrt[(x - y + a b c)^2], x - y + a b c > 0]
```

> ```
> Abs[a b c + x - y]
> ```

When I remove any of the `a`, `b`, `c`, `x` or `y` it returns the result without the `Abs`:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[(x - y + b c)^2], x - y + b c > 0]
```

> ```
> b d + x - y
> ```

I loose faith when I meet such behavior with Mathematica :-(

Even though

```
Simplify[Sqrt[expr^2], expr > 0] /. expr -> (x - y + a b c)
```

does fix the first issue how could I simplify this:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[(x - y + a ^2 b^2 c^2)^2], x > y]
```

Anyway, can anybody explain why this happens and propose a way to fix it for general expressions?

Comment: `PowerExpand[Sqrt[(x - y + a b c)^2]]` perhaps, with all of the caveats of `PowerExpand`.

Comment: `Simplify[Sqrt[expr^2], expr > 0] /. expr -> (x - y + a b c)` is pretty cheap but works..

Comment: Thanks @Öskå , what if I have something like : `Simplify[Sqrt[expr^2], x > y] /. expr -> (x - y + a ^2 b^2 c^2)` where the assumption is not the whole expression to be positive ?

Comment: @tchronis NP. Your example in the comments is quite different from the first one, hence my edit :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would appear that you can increase the number of assumptions variables that *Mathematica* will handle by altering a system option:

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 5}]

Simplify[Sqrt[(x - y + a b c)^2], x - y + a b c > 0]
(* a b c + x - y *)

Simplify[Sqrt[(x - y + a^2 b^2 c^2)^2], {x > y, {a, b, c} ∈ Reals}]
(* a^2 b^2 c^2 + x - y *)
```

Comment: Very Nice! I will check if it applies in all of my cases. Thanks @SimonWoods

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this option while "exploring" but its use was not obvious.  Can you give any other examples where it affects the result?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I have no experience with it - I just checked the system options to see if there was anything that might be responsible for the behaviour change between 4 and 5 variables.

Comment: I have experimented in much more complex expressions and when I increase AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables then memory consumption increases leading sometimes in kernel crashes. It would be interesting to write a routine to automatically determine the suitable number for each expression. That is adaptive Simplification ...

Answer (score 0):

It is since Mma does not know, what among x,y,a,b and c is positive and negative and, therefore, which their combination should be chosen, `x-y+abc`or `y-x-abc`. If you tell it, say, like this:

```
    Simplify[Sqrt[(x - y + a b c)^2], {x - y + a b c > 0, x > 0, a > 0, 
  b > 0, c > 0, y < 0}]
```

it will return the expected result:

```
(*   a b c + x - y  *)
```

Later edit. To address your question below. No, it is not right. Let us see:
The inequality `x - y + a b c > 0`has a lot of solutions depending on the signs of all these parameters:

```
 Reduce[x - y + a b c > 0]

(*   (a | b | y) \[Element] 
  Reals && ((x <= 
      y && ((c < 
          0 && ((b < 0 && a > (-x + y)/(b c)) || (b > 0 && 
             a < (-x + y)/(b c)))) || (c > 
          0 && ((b < 0 && a < (-x + y)/(b c)) || (b > 0 && 
             a > (-x + y)/(b c)))))) || (x > 
      y && ((c < 
          0 && ((b < 0 && a > (-x + y)/(b c)) || 
           b == 0 || (b > 0 && a < (-x + y)/(b c)))) || 
       c == 0 || (c > 
          0 && ((b < 0 && a < (-x + y)/(b c)) || 
           b == 0 || (b > 0 && a > (-x + y)/(b c)))))))   *)
```

Comment: Although nobody said that `x` or any other variable was negative or positive. Only the overall expression is positive.

Comment: But one constraint is enough for that right? Normally I have much more complex expressions to simplify and I cannot afford having more constraints than required. So this is a fix only for this and not the general case...

Comment: @ Öskå then not only Mma but you and me are unable to decide, how to write this expression without Àbs`. Anyway, I only explain why Mma behaves this way.

Comment: If `(x - y + a b c) > 0` then you and me and _Mathematica_ know that `Sqrt[(x - y + a b c)^2] = x - y + a b c`. That's the OP's point I guess.

Comment: @tchronis Please find my answer in the edit to the first one.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch thanks for your answer but it does not really help me because I want to make things as simple as possible. In my real project I have to simplify thousands expressions like that and I don't care about the shape of the N-dimensional region that satisfies the inequality.

Comment: @ Öskå Ok, you are right, it is my mistake.

Comment: @tchronis Sorry, I am not right.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch it's ok - thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Mathematically speaking, you are trying to specify a branch of the square-root function by an irrelevant assumption.  This can lead to totally bogus results.  Somewhat simplifying: Just because 9>0 does not mean that -3  is not also a square-root of 9.  Yeah, yeah some people think that Sqrt[explicit_positive_real] must mean the positive root. But it doesn't generalize, say to cube roots (etc).  Choosing a branch cut is independent of the sign of the radicand, mathematically. Math works that way.

Comment: In some optimization problems you may have constraints that set some quantities positive . So the variables that maximize the objective function may be expressed without Abs in a more presentable way. Also in that way simplifications reduce a lot the resulted formulas.

Comment: In that case you are talking about a different function which might be describable as a particular branch of the square root "function".  Mathematica has the Root[] function which makes it almost possible to talk correctly about the issue.  Certainly physical problems provide insight into which branch of a square-root is the useful one. A glance through a physics text should reveal that the "sign" of the radicand is not the key as to which branch has a correct "physical" properties. It is possible to write programs like PowerExpand. Sometimes produces nonsense.