# Simplification is not working properly for Complex functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have a Matrix whose eigenvectors are needed to be calculated and then I have to calculate the Projector out of it.
But due to some unavoidable(atleast up to now), I am not able to carry out the procedure.

```
(* Matrix definition *)
QEG = {{-(Exp[-I k]/Sqrt[2]), -((I Exp[-I k])/Sqrt[2])}, {-((I Exp[I k])/Sqrt[
   2]), -(Exp[I k]/Sqrt[2])}};

(* Matrix eigenvectors*)
EvQ = Eigenvectors[QEG];

(* Eigenvectors Normalization*)
NomQ = Simplify[Normalize[EvQ], Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals]];

(* Projectors*)
Projector1 = Simplify[KroneckerProduct[NomQ[[1]], Conjugate[NomQ[[1]]]], 
  Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals]] // MatrixForm
Projector2 = Simplify[KroneckerProduct[NomQ[[2]], Conjugate[NomQ[[2]]]], 
  Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals]] // MatrixForm
```

But the result for `NomQ` comes with `Abs` and the result of `Projector1/2` comes with `Conjugate`. Couldn't seem to simplify it.

I went through enlightening [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/remove-annoying-conjugate/16357)([s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31485/removing-abs-from-absa-expicb2)) where they used `ComplexExpand`, it didn't work here, unfortunately, only made it worse.

Comment: `NomQ = Assuming[Element[k, Reals],
  Normalize /@ EvQ // 
    ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify]`

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon, it worked but `Projector1` still has those hanging `Conjugate`. Can I use this expression to replace them? It seems bit numerically expensive

Comment: `(Projector1 = Assuming[Element[k, Reals],
      KroneckerProduct[NomQ[[1]], Conjugate[NomQ[[1]]]]] // 
     ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
    Simplify) // MatrixForm` Note that the `MatrixForm` formatting wrapper is isolated from the definition of `Projector1` by the use of parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that Normalize takes only vectors as input:

```
(*Matrix definition*)
QEG = {{-(Exp[-I k]/Sqrt[2]), -((I Exp[-I k])/
       Sqrt[2])}, {-((I Exp[I k])/Sqrt[2]), -(Exp[I k]/Sqrt[2])}};

(*Matrix eigenvectors*)
EvQ = Eigenvectors[QEG];

(*Eigenvectors Normalization*)
NomQ = 
 Table[Simplify[Normalize[QEG[[n]]], 
   Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals]], {n, 1, 2}];

(*Projectors*)
Projector1 = 
 Simplify[KroneckerProduct[NomQ[[1]], Conjugate[NomQ[[1]]]], 
   Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals]] // MatrixForm
Projector2 = 
 Simplify[KroneckerProduct[NomQ[[2]], Conjugate[NomQ[[2]]]], 
   Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals]] // MatrixForm
```

This gives:

> $$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}  \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{i}{2} \\ 
>  \frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \end{array} \right)$$

and

> $$\left( \begin{array}{cc}  \frac{1}{2} & \frac{i}{2} \\  -\frac{i}{2}
>  & \frac{1}{2} \\ \end{array} \right)$$

Comment: Thanks Fabian. Just a little change I misquote `QEG` instead of `EvQ`, in normalize function(I edited my question), now comes the problem. So result may change. Sorry for that